# Correct method to append in C

Tags: c, string

I have packets being captured in hex value and I am want to store them into a defined array. Finally when I do the puts it just print one value? Why is not working? Must I use strcat ?

```
char fullArray[1514];
        int i=0;
            for(i = 0; i < h->caplen; i++)
            {
                  printf("%02X ", p[i]);
                  printf("\n");
                  sprintf(fullArray,"%02X ",p[i]);
            }
puts(fullArray);
```

Comment: Need to update the buffer address to use sprintf; also snprintf is safer.

Comment: @Arsane what should I change in my code quite lost ?

Comment: I think you should study C arrays and strings a bit. C array is more primitive than arrays of other languages, little more than a glorified pointer (length is static, and not stored with array, for example). C string is just pointer to first char of string, and end of string is marked by 0-byte (which you are responsible to have there, mostly).

Answer (score 4):

`sprintf` outputs at the beginning of fullArray.

If you want to append after it, you should use `sprintf(fullArray + strlen(fullArray), ...)` to lookup for the null character. You can avoid calculating the length each time by using the return value of `sprintf`.

`strcat` will not enable `printf`-like formatting. So you can otherwise `sprintf` to a temporary buffer and use `strcat` to copy that buffer at the end of `fullArray`.

**Warning, you must be sure that your size of 1514 is enough to concatenate all those formatted strings.**

In the following example I hold two variables: a pointer to the next write location, and a remaining available size in your buffer. Each time `snprintf` is called, it will never write past the end of the buffer and I use its return value to update the two variables. There must at least remain 1 byte to hold the final `\0` that `snprintf` outputs but that is not counted in its return value.

```
char fullArray[1514];
char *nextwrite = &fullArray[0];
int buf_remaining_size = 1514;
int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < h->caplen; i++)
{
    if(buf_remaining_size <= 1) {
        /* your buffer is too small! Handle error */
        break;
    }

    printf("%02X\n", p[i]);
    int written = snprintf(nextwrite, buf_remaining_size, "%02X ", p[i]);    

    nextwrite += written;
    buf_remaining_size -= written;
}
```

Comment: @I dont get you your solution if I keep doing this strlen(fullArray) wouldnt I be adding 1514 always

Comment: No, `strlen` calculates the number of characters from the start of `fullArray` to the first NULL char. It is not `sizeof`.

Comment: I would advise against using `strlen`, since `sprintf` already returns the number of characters written.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev, I wrote about that in my §2. *“You can avoid calculating the length each time by using the return value of sprintf.”*

Comment: @Benoit: ah, ok, I just didn't notice that after seeing `strlen` mentioned.

Comment: @Benoit I dont get you what you meant by advice against using strlen?

Comment: @user2711681: It would not be as efficient, although still correct.

Comment: So what is better so far what Vijay suggested is working too.

Comment: @Benoit how to handle this "There must at least remain 1 byte to hold the final \0 that snprintf outputs but that is not counted in its return value." Must I add my array to 1515 ?

Comment: No, the condition `if(buf_remaining_size <= 1) {` checks that for you.

Comment: @Benoit if those hex values I want them to be human readable I tried this printf("%c\n", p[i]); but not appearing not well

Answer (score 1):

Your code will result in only having `p[(h->caplen)-1]` in the array.
You need:

```
for(i = 0; i < h->caplen; i++)
            {
                  printf("%02X ", p[i]);
                  printf("\n");
                  if(i==0)
                  sprintf(fullArray,"%02X ",p[i]);
                  else if(strlen(fullArray)<(h->caplen)){
                      char a[10];
                      sprintf(a,"%02X",p[i]);
                      strcat(fullArray,a);
                      }
             }
```

Comment: its working but I want to understand what u doing here first line if i==0 u put into the sprintf ok. Then next you check if the length is less then the total length. What u define the char a[10] ?

Comment: for the first iteration we have to copy the character to the array since the array is uninitialized. from the second time, you just need to append the retrieved value in all iterations provided your fullarray is not getting completely filled. So we will check for strlen before we append.